# VSTS issue with applying Build Version Number to the assemblies

Tags: c#, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an issue with applying Build Version to my assemblies in the VSTS Pipeline.

In the past this was achieved was using MSBuild Targets.

My AssemblyInfo.cs class in the projects within the solution have the following setup:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Demo App")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Release x86")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Demo App Ltd")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("© 2018. All Rights Reserved.")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.1.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.1.0")]
```

Here is my build pipeline request:
[image]

In my build pipeline i build the solution first and then when that succeeds it calls one of the Manifest Versioning Build Tasks called VersionAssemblies to update .NET Assemblies. But its not updating the Product Version and File Version after the solution has been built by the server.

Here is my current setup regarding this task that is in my pipeline

[image]

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong because when i examined the assembly files that have been built it only contains the default version i.e 1.0.1.0.

1. So what am i doing wrong?
2. Can someone advise what i can try next please?

**UPDATE**

It works if i move the Task before i build the solution. I suspect this is the correct way but can someone confirm please?

Comment: That's the correct way. It patches the sources in-place, not the binaries.

Comment: Since your problem has been solved, you can added the update as answer and mark it.

Answer (score 4):

Issue can be resolved by doing the following: Put the "Version.NET task" before building the solution task. It patches the sources in-place, not the binaries.